# Docker rancher/agent won't start

Tags: ubuntu, docker, rancher

Like the title suggests i can't start the rancher/agent:v0.8.2 to add my host to rancher.

The logs that come from docker when trying to start it:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(111, 'Connection refused'))
```

I have tried clearing my /var/lib/rancher/ folder as suggested by other fixes but didn't work.

I had rancher installed before with the agent and network and worked as expected from the first try. I have deleted them all and now they seem not to work anymore, giving me the error stated above. I had even reinstalled my docker and tried again but still with no luck.

I'm no expert in docker, linux or rancher.

Comment: How you are adding host to rancher?

Comment: You should try posting any Rancher issues to their forum, http://forums.rancher.com, you'll get an answer quite quickly.

Comment: @AbhijeetKamble Through their infrastructure administration platfom.

Comment: Please check docker version on your host if compatible to run rancher agent

Comment: When i have tested i had the latest version of docker. There shouldn't be a problem on docker side.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are doing the same thing I did: running Rancher and a Rancher agent on the same machine.
Take a look at this [github issue](https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/4175). The TLDR; Look under Admin > Settings  for the Host Registration URL. Make sure it isn't set to localhost.

[image: Rancher Host Registration URL]

Comment: Thank you, this just made me realise how messed up my setup was.

Answer (score 0):

First: make sure your rancher server container is running.
Second: get the correct command from your rancher server web frontend.
For example:

```
sudo docker run -d --privileged -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock rancher/agent:v0.8.2 http://192.168.4.29:8080/v1/scripts/92028FE9D7332113255D:1456113600000:18hrbqQzJD4A3UlKlM2EEbGZ5Y
```

The 92028FExxx part is generated randomly, So make sure you get the correct one.